# if condition in a vvv-init.sh file of vagrant

Tags: linux, bash, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm creating my vvv-init.sh file in my new Vagrant, but I can't use the if condition correctly. I've tried as the example says here
https://github.com/varying-vagrant-vagrants/vvv/wiki/Auto-site-Setup
and as other tutorials says but it doesn't work

This is the content

```
while [ ! -d mydirectory.com ]
do
    echo "Try to download mydirectory.com repo..."
    git clone -b development git@github.com:mydirectory.com.git

    if[ -d mydirectory.com ] 
    then
        echo "mydirectory.com repo Downloaded"
    else
        echo "Error downloading mydirectory.com repo. Press anykey to try again"
        pause
    fi
done
```

The error is

```
Hi mercypatin! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
./vvv-init.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./vvv-init.sh: line 7: `    then'
```

And I've tried  using

```
if[ -d mydirectory.com ]; then
```

Without "then" and

```
if[ -d mydirectory.com ] then
```

In this case it gives me an "else error"

Comment: Consider [this pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D) and then use [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to lint your script.

Comment: the problem was that the i  need to have a space between "if" and "["